# How to convert emphasis to italic tinymce?

Tags: wysiwyg

I use [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) with [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com) (Version 3.5.11) and I would like to convert emphasis to italic. How to do that?